# MySQL Server Has Gone Away - Tried Everything

Tags: mysql

I am executing the query below and after a few seconds I get a "MySQL serer has gone away" error. I tried to increase wait_timeout, max_allowed_packet and some other variables suggested by people but I can't fix it.

```
SELECT tmp.filter_group_id,
       tmp.filter_id,
       tmp.product_id
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM
 (SELECT f.filter_group_id,
     pf.filter_id,
     p.product_id,
     (IFNULL(
       (SELECT price
        FROM oc_product_special AS ps
        WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id
          AND ps.customer_group_id = '1'
          AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00'
                OR ps.date_start < NOW())
               AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00'
                    OR ps.date_end > NOW()))
        ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1), 
        IFNULL(
          (SELECT price
           FROM oc_product_discount AS pd2
           WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id
             AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1'
             AND pd2.quantity >= '1'
             AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00'
                   OR pd2.date_start < NOW())
                  AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00'
                       OR pd2.date_end > NOW()))
               ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1), p.price)) * 1) AS mf_price
      FROM oc_product AS p
      INNER JOIN oc_product_filter AS pf ON pf.product_id = p.product_id
      INNER JOIN oc_filter AS f ON f.filter_id = pf.filter_id
      INNER JOIN oc_product_to_store AS p2s ON p2s.product_id = p.product_id
      AND p2s.store_id = 0
      INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category AS p2c ON p2c.product_id = p.product_id
      INNER JOIN oc_category_path AS cp ON cp.category_id = p2c.category_id
      WHERE p.date_available <= NOW()
        AND p.status = '1'
        AND (FIND_IN_SET(18, p.mfilter_values))
        AND cp.path_id IN(6) ) AS tmp
   WHERE (mf_price > 40
          AND mf_price < 701) ) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.filter_group_id NOT IN(1);
```

^ This is the query causing the trouble which I got from the log file.

If I change the "SELECT tmp.filter_group_id, tmp.filter_id, tmp.product_id" part with "SELECT tmp.*" the query works fine and returns the results in under 0.2 seconds. Unfortunatelly changing it wouldn't solve my problem as there is another query, something like:

```
SELECT mfp.filter_group_id,
           mfp.filter_id,
           COUNT(DISTINCT mfp.product_id) FROM ([THE QUERY ABOVE]) as mfp
GROUP BY mfp.filter_group_id,
           mfp.filter_id;
```

So I have to get the first query working. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is the mysql.log

```
18:43:06 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=2147483648
read_buffer_size=16777216
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2852645 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1c6215421c0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff64e61d542    mysqld.exe!Item_subselect::exec()[item_subselect.cc:575]
7ff64e6231b2    mysqld.exe!Item_singlerow_subselect::val_decimal()[item_subselect.cc:1259]
7ff64e490f53    mysqld.exe!Item_func_ifnull::decimal_op()[item_cmpfunc.cc:3382]
7ff64e51bf4b    mysqld.exe!Item_func_numhybrid::val_decimal()[item_func.cc:1453]
7ff64e511586    mysqld.exe!Item_func_mul::decimal_op()[item_func.cc:2067]
7ff64e51bf4b    mysqld.exe!Item_func_numhybrid::val_decimal()[item_func.cc:1453]
7ff64e4e46ac    mysqld.exe!Item_direct_ref::val_decimal()[item.cc:8598]
7ff64e48ef18    mysqld.exe!Arg_comparator::compare_decimal()[item_cmpfunc.cc:1763]
7ff64e49d4b1    mysqld.exe!Item_func_gt::val_int()[item_cmpfunc.cc:2608]
7ff64e4e3a41    mysqld.exe!Item::val_bool()[item.cc:211]
7ff64e49cb9c    mysqld.exe!Item_cond_and::val_int()[item_cmpfunc.cc:6102]
7ff64ea3682e    mysqld.exe!evaluate_join_record()[sql_executor.cc:1483]
7ff64ea3a437    mysqld.exe!sub_select()[sql_executor.cc:1288]
7ff64ea369b5    mysqld.exe!evaluate_join_record()[sql_executor.cc:1634]
7ff64ea3a437    mysqld.exe!sub_select()[sql_executor.cc:1288]
7ff64ea356c1    mysqld.exe!do_select()[sql_executor.cc:941]
7ff64ea3703b    mysqld.exe!JOIN::exec()[sql_executor.cc:199]
7ff64e608571    mysqld.exe!handle_query()[sql_select.cc:185]
7ff64e4c27f6    mysqld.exe!execute_sqlcom_select()[sql_parse.cc:4947]
7ff64e4c46de    mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:2597]
7ff64e4c7faa    mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:5363]
7ff64e4c12c9    mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1287]
7ff64e4c226a    mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:854]
7ff64e469634    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:295]
7ff64ee7ad82    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2195]
7ff64eba46fb    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
7ff64ef3b39f    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
7ff64ef3b5ea    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
7ff887d48364    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff888b65e91    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1c6215902a0): (18:43:06 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=2147483648
read_buffer_size=16777216
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2852645 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1c6215421c0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff64e61d542    mysqld.exe!Item_subselect::exec()[item_subselect.cc:575]
7ff64e6231b2    mysqld.exe!Item_singlerow_subselect::val_decimal()[item_subselect.cc:1259]
7ff64e490f53    mysqld.exe!Item_func_ifnull::decimal_op()[item_cmpfunc.cc:3382]
7ff64e51bf4b    mysqld.exe!Item_func_numhybrid::val_decimal()[item_func.cc:1453]
7ff64e511586    mysqld.exe!Item_func_mul::decimal_op()[item_func.cc:2067]
7ff64e51bf4b    mysqld.exe!Item_func_numhybrid::val_decimal()[item_func.cc:1453]
7ff64e4e46ac    mysqld.exe!Item_direct_ref::val_decimal()[item.cc:8598]
7ff64e48ef18    mysqld.exe!Arg_comparator::compare_decimal()[item_cmpfunc.cc:1763]
7ff64e49d4b1    mysqld.exe!Item_func_gt::val_int()[item_cmpfunc.cc:2608]
7ff64e4e3a41    mysqld.exe!Item::val_bool()[item.cc:211]
7ff64e49cb9c    mysqld.exe!Item_cond_and::val_int()[item_cmpfunc.cc:6102]
7ff64ea3682e    mysqld.exe!evaluate_join_record()[sql_executor.cc:1483]
7ff64ea3a437    mysqld.exe!sub_select()[sql_executor.cc:1288]
7ff64ea369b5    mysqld.exe!evaluate_join_record()[sql_executor.cc:1634]
7ff64ea3a437    mysqld.exe!sub_select()[sql_executor.cc:1288]
7ff64ea356c1    mysqld.exe!do_select()[sql_executor.cc:941]
7ff64ea3703b    mysqld.exe!JOIN::exec()[sql_executor.cc:199]
7ff64e608571    mysqld.exe!handle_query()[sql_select.cc:185]
7ff64e4c27f6    mysqld.exe!execute_sqlcom_select()[sql_parse.cc:4947]
7ff64e4c46de    mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:2597]
7ff64e4c7faa    mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:5363]
7ff64e4c12c9    mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1287]
7ff64e4c226a    mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:854]
7ff64e469634    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:295]
7ff64ee7ad82    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2195]
7ff64eba46fb    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
7ff64ef3b39f    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
7ff64ef3b5ea    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
7ff887d48364    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff888b65e91    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1c6215902a0): SELECT tmp.filter_group_id, ... the query above)
Connection ID (thread ID): 10
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

EDIT 2:
Btw this is MySQL 5.7.9 server which is running on my windows machine I am using WAMP.

I have the same db (with at least 5x more rows) on 2 of my shared host's server:

1. MySQL 5.6.23
2. Percona 5.6.28-76.1

Both run the query almost instantly.

Comment: Did you check the error-log file?

Comment: Is this MySQL Server version 5.7.9, perhaps?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes it is 5.7.9

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have upgraded to 5.7.14 and the problem is fixed! Is there a bug in 5.7.9 related to this?

Comment: Yes, I suspected it might be [Bug #79787](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79787), with a crash and a stack trace ending in item_subselect.cc, like yours.  It's anecdotally claimed to be working in 5.7.10 although the official follow-through on the bug tracker is pretty soft at the moment and no explanation has been provided for what exactly they fixed (it had apparently been fixed before this particular report was filed) so I'd like to provide a better explanation in an answer here if I can pin it down.  Did you have any other logged warnings or errors from right before the crash?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I always cleared the logs and ran the problematic query. So the log above is the only one I have. _If you can add your comment above as an answer to the question, I will mark it as the accepted answer._

Comment: Thank you.  I plan to do that, but first I would like to identify what was changed, presumably in 5.7.10, that actually resolved the problem.

Comment: Found it.  Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to have the same symptoms as [Bug #79787](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79787).  Though not clearly documented there, this appears to have been resolved in MySQL Server 5.7.10, which was actually released a few days before the bug was reported.

> A query with nested derived tables and scalar subqueries in the select list of the derived tables might in some cases cause a server exit. (Bug #22062023)
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-10.html#mysqld-5-7-10-bug

"A server exit" is a euphemism for "a hard crash."

This appears to have been caused by a [defect](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/d751313d9640cf70b97382971866992eef5406e7) that improperly considered a column "unused" and optimized it away, eventually leading to an invalid memory access, since the column was, in fact, used in the outer query.

Upgrading to 5.7.10 or later resolves the issue, which may have been introduced early in 5.7 development, and thus may not be present at all prior to 5.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 'composite' index to ps and pd2:

```
INDEX(customer_group_id, priority, price)
```

If it still fails, write a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com ; MySQL should never crash.

Comment: Tried it. Still crashing.